# Creating directory symlinks in a nested loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.  I'm trying to find a list of directories in the $HOME/dotfiles directory for each of a list of users, and then from that list create a symlink of that directory in $HOME.

```
# Get list of directories in $HOME/dotfiles
- name: Get list of directories in $HOME/dotfiles
  find:
    paths: "/home/{{ user.username }}/dotfiles"
    file_type: directory
    recurse: false
  register: dirs_matched
  become: "{{ user.username }}"
  loop: "{{ users|flatten(levels=1)}}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: user

# Symlink any directories in dotfiles to $HOME
- name: Symlink dirs in ~/dotfiles to $HOME
  file:
    src: "{{item.0.path}}"
    dest: "/home/{{item.1.username}}/{{item.0.path|basename}}"
    state: link
    force: true
  loop: "{{ dirs_matched.files |product(users)|list }}"
  when: dirs_matched.matched > 0
```

I do get results but they are in dirs_matched.results.files.  I'm not sure how to map the results to the file module loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) loop but not `nested/(product)`.
For every top-level item (user) iterate every subelement (files).

```
- name: Symlink dirs in ~/dotfiles to $HOME
  file:
    src: "{{ item.1.path }}"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.0.user.username }}/{{ item.1.path | basename }}"
    state: link
    force: true
  loop: "{{ dirs_matched.results | subelements('files') }}"
```

`when` condition is not required because loop over zero elements does nothing.

Comment: Where is the users list? It looks like it would only iterate over the files in dirs_matched.results.

Comment: If you look closely to the `dirs_matched.results` you'll find out that every element of it contains original loop's item (in your case `loop_var` is `user`). It can be accessed as `dirs_matched.results[0].user` for first iteration and so on. Then `subelements` generates a list of items with `[0]` as parent element and `[1]` as subelement – thus `item.0.user` is the element of original loop and `item.1` is a file data.